# How to find watt hours of MacBook?

Tags: battery, power, power-management, energy, statistics

I see the latests Macbook Pro 16" has a [100 watthour battery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E92TnPdDgEU#t=3m30s) - how do I find the equivalent stat for my current Macbook given the info under About -> System Report -> Hardware -> Battery Information?

[image]

My guess is take the full charge capacity (3582). Also divide the mV (milli volts?) by 1000 to get volts, then use a calculator or [conversion table](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/common/watts-amps.php). But I'm not exactly sure what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct. Watt=ampere*Voltage, Wh=Ah*V, so 3582/1000*12553/1000=44.96 Wh.